# JavaScript modules import / export

Tags: javascript, import, module, export

I just learned about modules in JS. I'm trying to make this work on my machine and I still have a couple of questions because it only works in certain cases.

I've seen and tried examples from youtube videos with the following syntax:

```
// number.js
export const num = 5;

// main.js
import { num } from './number.js'


//This throws the following error:

import { num } from './number.js';
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
    at wrapSafe (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1072:16)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1122:27)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1178:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1002:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:901:14)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47
```

On my end it only works when I do this:

```
// number.js
const num = 10;
module.exports =  { num };

// main.js
const num = require('./number.js');
```

Could anyone enlighten me and tell me what's the difference and if I'm doing is technically correct?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your `export` and `import` declarations are just fine, it's just that the environment doesn't know that `main.js` is meant to be a module.

If you're doing this on Node.js, see [their documentation](https://nodejs.org/api/esm.html) for details, but the short version is either put `"type": "module"` in your `package.json` or use the extension `.mjs`.

If you're doing this on a browser, the `script` tag for the `main.js` file needs to have `type="module"` so that the JavaScript engine knows it's a module. Here's a [live example on CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/cranky-archimedes-ibn93):

`index.html`:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <script src="./main.js" type="module"></script>
    <title>Export / Import Example</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

`main.js`:

```
import { num } from "./number.js";

document.body.appendChild(document.createTextNode(`num = ${num}`));
```

`number.js`:

```
export const num = 5;
```

(Note that since `type="module"` automatically defers the script, there's no need to put it at the bottom of the `body` like you do with non-module scripts.)

Comment: Hi TJ, thank you for your answer.
I've tried that too by creating a boilerplate html file and including the script tags:
```<script type="module" src="./main.js" ></script>```
I'm getting these errors though:

```Access to script at 'file:///Users/Mike/Desktop/test%20environment/main.js' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.```

```main.js:1 Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FAILED```

Comment: @MikeRophone - It looks like with your browser you need to be using a server, not opening files directly. In general, you want to be using `http:` or `https:` URLs when doing web development, there are several things that are slightly different when you're using `file:` URLs. For a reliable experience, always go through a server.

Comment: I see, I will try that then and post back the results!
Thanks for your help!

Comment: @MikeRophone - FWIW, I cover modules in depth in my new book coming out in a couple of months (Chapter 13). ;-) If you're interested, see my profile for details.

Comment: That would have been my next question: where do you suggest I can learn all this in-depth :)

Will check out your book!

Comment: It works now. I installed the "Live Server" extension in VS Code and it runs perfectly!
Thanks again for your help!

Answer (score 0):

module.exports() function is default function that come with nodejs and is part of requirejs module. On other hand import and export are more of ES6 and above feature for which I believe you would need either webpack module or babel module to transpile it into normal ES5 syntax which browser render engine can understand at runtime. Here is the link for above two modules.

webpack - https://webpack.js.org/

babel - https://babeljs.io/

Comment: ESM (ECMAScript Modules) are natively supported by all modern browsers and Node.js. You don't **need** a bundler unless you need to target obsolete browsers. You may choose to use one, but you don't need to.